# c# Array generics with each array item of different type

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, collections

I have a struct defining some pair type wich uses generics:

```
struct SomeNameValuePair<T>
{
    string TypeName;
    T Value;
}
```

and a need to declare an array of SomeNameValuePair:

```
SomeNameValuePair<T>[] someNameValuePair=new SomeNameValuePair<T>[3];
```

The problem is that I need different types for Value property for different array Items.
In code it is much easier to understand:

```
SomeNameValuePair<int> tempSomeNameValuePair0;

tempSomeNameValuePair0.TypeName="int";
tempSomeNameValuePair0.Value=10;


SomeNameValuePair<double> tempSomeNameValuePair1;

tempSomeNameValuePair1.TypeName="double";
tempSomeNameValuePair1.Value=10.5;

tempSomeNameValuePair2.TypeName="string";
tempSomeNameValuePair2.Value="Random String";

someNameValuePair[0]=tempSomeNameValuePair0
someNameValuePair[1]=tempSomeNameValuePair1
someNameValuePair[2]=tempSomeNameValuePair2
```

Obviusly my code does not work as when instantiating array `someNameValuePair=new SomeNameValuePair<T>[3];`, I am committing the array property Value of its items to be of type T.

Is there any way to achieve my goal in C#?

Comment: Please re-check your code. Are you missing come brackets or is it just me?

Comment: In your real project, do you use the same types you used in the example? I'm just thinking of a common base class. If you were using classes with a common ancestor, you could use it for such a generic collection. Otherwise I'd use `object`.

Comment: @DmitryPopov No, the types above are just fot the sake of the example. The reason I need to do it this way is in some cases types are unknown at compile time.

Comment: @geraldCelente Generics are more like compile-time. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708090/c-sharp-generics-is-it-runtime-or-compile-time-polymorphism

Comment: No, you can't achieve this in C#. Mainly because it's inconsistent and unusable, what type is `someNameValuePair[i].Value`?  Use `dynamic` or just `System.Object`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Exactly I know my code is wrong because of that. I wonder if there is some way to achieve my objective by some other code.

Comment: Ok thanks. I remembered that unlike C++, C# supported run time polimorfism. However, from the answer you pointed me at that is not 100% the case. I will use object as suggested by @Dmitri Popov

Comment: Since your ValuePairs are not the same type (which leads me to wonder how they would be used), you cannot use a Generic or Array because there is no one T - they are different.  An ArrayList will work (and a rare instance when it is the better choice).

Comment: you can define another generic struct in which you define your array, otherwise object or dynamic are your only solution

Comment: Ok yhank you all. I will go that way.

Comment: "I am committing the array property Value of its items to be of type T" -- this doesn't even make sense. There is no "type T". That's just a place holder. The way you want to use your type, it shouldn't even be generic; just make `Value`'s type `object`. If you would show a reasonable code example, that illustrates _why_ you think it makes sense to put all these unrelated objects into the same array, maybe a useful answer could be provided. Otherwise, it's just not clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need a non-generic base class:

```
class SomeNameValuePairBase
{
    string TypeName;
}
```

then all your generic items inherit from this base class:
(its class, not struct, because structs cant use inheritance)

```
class SomeNameValuePair<T> : SomeNameValuePairBase
{
    T Value;
}
```

This alllows you to declare an array of your items:

```
SomeNameValuePairBase[] someNameValuePair = new SomeNameValuePairBase[3];
```

and use it like so:

```
someNameValuePair[0] = new SomeNewValuePair<double>();
```

Furthermore you should not work with 'TypeName' but use the C# 'is' operator instead:

```
if(someValuePair[0] is someValuePair<double>) ...
```