# How to cast an IEnumerable<object> to an IEnumerable<runtime type>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, casting

I'm trying to accomplish the following.

Suppose I have this data model:

```
public class Article
{
     public ICollection<string> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

These tags are retrieved from a database. My database's API returns them to me as a `List<object>`.

Therefore, I need to make a conversion from `List<object>` to something that implements `ICollection<string>`.

I am aware of the LINQ `Cast<T>()` method that cast its elements to the given type and returns the converted `IEnumerable<T>`.

However, I cannot use `Cast<string>()` because that would always cast my `List<object>` to `IEnumerable<string>`, not giving any options for models that have `ICollection<double>` properties (or any other type).

I can use reflection and get the generic type parameter:

```
Type genericArg = collectionType.GetGenericArguments().First();
```

But that would leave me with a runtime `Type`, which I cannot use as `Cast<genericArg>()`.

How can I cast an `IEnumerable<object>` to an `IEnumerable` of a dynamic `Type`?.

I should note that no complex types are allowed on my model, so anything like:

```
public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
```

will not happen. I only handle primitive types.

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with Cast<T>() appropriately for each case.

Comment: How would you use these values if you don't know what type they are?

Comment: "My database's API returns them to me as a `List<object>`" Seems like fixing the API would fix your issue.  Any reason why it can't return different  collection types?

Comment: @DStanley Database' API is out of my hands (I'm using AWS DynamoDB SDK). I can correctly convert `List<object>` to `List<string>` using `Cast<string>()` and the application works fine, but I am looking forward to an alternative that doesn't stick me with just `string` and doesn't require me to build `if` cases for each primitive type

Comment: I cannot use any generic method, because I don't know `T` until runtime. This mapping method will be called by many models and sometimes I must cast to `IEnumerable<string>` and sometimes to `IEnumerable<double>`

Comment: Why would getting a typed `IEnumerable<T>` help you if you don't know what type it holds until runtime? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @31eee384 My goal is to have a model containing an `IEnumerable<string>` or `IEnumerable<X>` property which would be correctly mapped from a `IEnumerable<object>` that my database returns

Comment: @MatiCicero But you at some point have to know the compile-time type otherwise you won't be able to _use_ the model.

Answer (score 7):

You have a basic misunderstanding about casting.

**The result type of a casting operation must be known at compile time.**¹

Consider the following example:

```
string a = "abc";
object b = (object)a;
string c = (string)b;
```

The *runtime type* of `a`, `b` and `c` is the same. It's `string`. The *compile-time type* is different. Casting is only relevant for the compile-time type.

Thus, the answer to your question

> How to cast an `IEnumerable<object>` to an `IEnumerable<runtime type>`

is: You don't. Casting does not make sense for runtime types.

---

That said, let me offer a solution to your real problem: Let's say you have an `IEnumerable<object> values`, a `Type myTargetType` and want to create a `List<typeof(myTargetType)>` containing the values.

First, you create the list using reflection:

```
var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(myTargetType);
IList myList = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
```

And then you fill the list:

```
foreach (var item in values)
{
    myList.Add(item);
}
```

Obviously, `Add` will [throw an ArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310301(v=vs.110).aspx) if an entry of `values` is *not* of runtime type `myTargetType`.

---

¹ The result type can be a generic type, but [generic type parameters have to be specified at compile time as well](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12708090/87698).

Comment: "The result type of a casting operation must be known at compile time" - not true - you can cast to a generic type - that's how Linq's `Cast<T>` works.

Comment: @DStanley: True, but generic types must be known at compile time as well: You can only call `Cast<T>` if you provide it with a concrete type or another generic type. (And, in the latter case, the same argument can be made for *that* type. There has to be a concrete type somewhere at the end of the call chain.) You cannot call it with a runtime type. I'll clarify this in my question to avoid misunderstandings.

Answer (score 1):

I believe System.Convert has what you need:

```
Type genericArg = collectionType.GetGenericArguments().First();
foreach(var obj in collection) {
    yield return Convert.ChangeType(obj, genericArg);
}
```

Comment: If you assume his DB layer handles getting the correct type, then yes.  This solution allows him to specify the destination collection type and as long as conversion rules exist it will work.

Answer (score 0):

`Enumerable.Cast<T>(this IEnumerable source)` is normally what you'd be looking for.  It is possible to use reflection to close the generic type yourself if different variations are required:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var source = new List<object> {
            "foo",
            "bar",
            "baz"
        };

        var type = typeof(string); // or however you find out the type

        var castMethod = typeof(Enumerable)
            .GetMethod("Cast").MakeGenericMethod(
            new[] {
                type
            });

        var result = (IEnumerable<string>)
            castMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] {source});

        foreach (var str in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str.ToUpper());
        }
    }
}
```

The other problem is that it is not meaningful to cast from one `List<T>` to another - the generic parameter is *invariant*, because the collection is read-write.  (Arrays allow some such casting for historical reasons.)  If you're only reading, though, the `IEnumerable<T>` returned from `Cast` is sufficient.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the type of `T` until runtime

Comment: @MatiCicero You can close it at runtime with reflection if need be.

Comment: @MatiCicero I've added an example of closing the generic at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a generic method which take result from your database api and return appropriate collection as per your model, something like below:

```
private ICollection<T> RetrieveTags()
{
      // Get tags using database api

      return tags.Cast<T>();
 }
```

Then call this method to get model as needed, for example:

```
ICollection<int>  t1 = RetrieveTags<int>();
ICollection<string>  t2 = RetrieveTags<string>();
```